# Populating jTextfield with data from database through jTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have a nasty problem, to the point, I have a jTable which gets populated with questions from a database, in that database the are questions and answers, 1 questions has 4 answers, all the answers are in one table and can be tell apart only by the question_id.
My question to you, how can I populate jTextFields with data from asnwers table by clicking on a field in jTable which shows Questions?

This is my code so far for the table click event

```
 private void tblQuestionsMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

    try{
        int row = tblQuestions.getSelectedRow();
        String Table_click = (tblQuestions.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM gameanswers WHERE question_id ='"+Table_click+"'";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next());

        String ans = rs.getString("answers"); 
        jTextField1.setText(ans);
        String ans2 = rs.getString("answers");
        jTextField2.setText(ans2);

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
}

}
```

Now what should I write for ans2 so that it doesnt display the same value as ans?

Comment: I am not sure about what your problem is.is that in a jtable the answers from db have to displayed.then why you need them as jtextfield.explain your problem briefly..

Comment: In Jtable I have questions displayed, when I click on the specific question I want to retrieve answers that are connected to this question and display them in jtextfields.

Comment: Ok So I am able to dosplay one answer in Jtextfield but how do I display answers with question_id identical to the one I click on the table?

Comment: i didn't get it again.do you want to display one answer or multiple options to find answer.as you mentioned as four answers but you retrieved only one from db...are you trying a quiz or like that.i am clear about your problem

Comment: yes something like a quiz, when I click on a question 4 answers should show in 4 different textfields

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Grab all 4 answers and set them to 4 textfields ..

Comment: yes Kleo, Thats what Im trying to do

Comment: after showing what you are gonna do. are you gonna pick any one answer.if then there is no use using textfield.

Comment: after showing I dont want to do anything, just show them